# execute awk script with functions on remote servers

Tags: bash, awk

I have a awk scrip which includes functions like below:

```
for file in logfile.log; 
do 
    echo "File Name- "$file; 
    grep -v "Some Text" $file | awk -F [:\ ] '{sub(/T/, " "); if($8~500) CNT[$1":"$2]++} END {for (c in CNT) print c, "--", CNT[c]}' | sort; 
    echo "==============Done with $file=================="; 
done
```

But i want to execute this script on many remove servers, so i just login to our deployment (Which basically have access to all the server that i want to execute) and i am getting many compilation errors, I am using the following code:

```
for server in 01 02 03 04; do 
ssh web_user@webserver$server '
hostname -f;
cd /logs/dir/path;
for file in log-file-name.log; 
do 
    echo "File Name- "$file; 
    grep -v "Some Text" $file | awk -F [:\ ] '{sub(/T/, " "); if($8~500) CNT[$1":"$2]++} END {for (c in CNT) print c, "--", CNT[c]}' | sort; 
    echo "==============Done with $file=================="; 
done
'  2>&1 | grep -v 'THIS SYSTEM IS RESTRICTED'; done
```

Can someone please help me on this? My problem is though this script dosent have any compilation errors, i am getting many compilation errors.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: There are no functions in the awk script you posted. What do you think `for file in logfile.log;` does? There is nothing being compiled in your scripts so you aren't getting compilation errors, maybe you mean syntax errors or runtime errors? If you are getting errors, pls post the error messages.

Comment: Hello Morton, for file in logfiles.log - this will loop more than one file, just for testing i mentioned one file, but i need  to loop more than one file so i took this for loop. The error  message that i am getting is ---> webserveriw01.ceso.com
bash: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 6: `             grep -v "Some text" $file | awk -F [:\ ] \{sub(/T/, " "); if($8~500) CNT[$1":"$2]++} END {for (c in CNT) print c, "--", CNT[c]}\ | sort; '

Comment: awk is perfectly capable of opening multiple files (`awk 'script' file1 file2 ...`), you don't need a loop. [edit] your question to include the error message, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, a single quote (`'`) escapes all following characters except for other single quotes. Because of that, things like `{sub...` in the OP will be interpreted by your local script.

To pass the script this way to the remote `bash` (the one opened by `ssh`), you need to:

- Enclose the entire script within single quotes.
- Replace every single quote `'` inside your script (not the outer ones!) by `'\''`. How this works: the first `'` ends the current quotation; the `\'` includes a quoted single apostrophe; the last `'` reopens the quotation.

Example script:

```
foo=bar
echo 'foo=$foo'
echo "foo=$foo"
```

Expected output:

```
foo=$foo
foo=bar
```

Example invocation "by hand", i.e., this is something you would type in a terminal:

```
ssh server '
foo=bar
echo '\''foo=$foo'\''
echo "foo=$foo"
'
```

However, there is a way to avoid all this quoting business: you could save the original script (with normal single quotes) in a file `myscript`, and run instead:

```
ssh server "$(cat myscript)"
```

This way, the local `bash` will no longer be confused by the single quotes appearing in `myscript`, because the entire content will be quoted.

Comment: Hello David, Thank you so much for your time and help, but still i am getting following exception:                                                                             webserveriw01.ceso.com
bash: -c: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 6: `             grep -v "Some text" $file | awk -F [:\ ] \{sub(/T/, " "); if($8~500) CNT[$1":"$2]++} END {for (c in CNT) print c, "--", CNT[c]}\ | sort; '

Comment: Thank you so much David, Its work perfectly for me, you made my day :)